# Retrieving the result of a bash command run from ssh into a variable

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

The following command runs well when i run it localy on the dsired machine:

```
app_name=*some_proccess_name*
pid=`pgrep $app_name | tail -n 1`
```

But when i run it in the following way, from a remote pc using ssh it dosn't work:

```
pid=$(ssh $USER_NAME@$HOST_NAME "echo `pgrep $app_name | tail -n 1`")
```

The value of pid afterwards is just blank. I am not sure what's wrong (just to clarify i have tried several processes names that are all running on the target pc- that's not the problem ).

P.S when i run the command without echo, like that, i just get stuck inside the remote pc and have to use exit in order to get unstuck and return to my local pc:

```
pid=$(ssh tester@mir1 "`pgrep indicator-apple | tail -n 1`")
```

Comment: When you write, `"\`pgrep indicator-apple | tail -n 1\`"` with backticks inside double quotes, your shell will run that command as a subshell and *then* send the result of that command as an extra argument to `ssh`.  Remove the backticks, they are unnecessary: `pid=$(ssh tester@mir1 "pgrep indicator-apple | tail -n 1")`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66581/bash-shell-ssh-remote-script-capture-output-and-exit-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Less is more

```
pid=$(ssh tester@mir1 pgrep indicator-apple \| tail -n 1)
```

Comment: I'd recommend explicitly quoting the entire thing, not just the pipe character; `ssh` combines multiple arguments into a single command string in a non-terribly-well-defined way, so you may as well do it yourself. `ssh tester@mir1 'pgrep indicator-apple | tail -n 1'`